# Test Case for Trigger(before insert, before update) in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Anyone please help me to write test case for 100% code coverage for following trigger in apex

```
trigger ETicketAirlineUrlTrigger on E_Ticket__c (before insert, before update) {

  for(E_Ticket__c etNew : Trigger.New)
  {
    if(etNew.Airline__c =='Virgin Australia')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.virginaustralia.com/Personal/Bookings/Managebookings/index.htm">Virgin Australia</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Virgin Atlantic')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://www.virgin-atlantic.com/en/us/manageyourflights/updatebooking/index.jsp">Virgin Atlantic</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Virgin America')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.virginamerica.com/view-itinerary.html">Virgin America</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='US AIR')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://reservations.usairways.com/Default.aspx">US AIR</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='United Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.united.com/page/genericpage/0,,52172,00.html?navSource=dropDown&linkTitle=itineraries">United Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Turkish Air')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www4.thy.com/mybookings/reservations.tk?target=view&lang=en">Turkish Air</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Thai Air')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.thaiair.com/AWR_PREM/view-trip.jsp">Thai Air</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Swiss Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.swiss.com/web/EN/Pages/index.aspx?Country=US">Swiss Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Southwest Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://www.southwest.com/flight/lookup-air-reservation.html?int=GSUBNAV-AIR-RETRIEVE&forceNe...">Southwest Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='South African')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://www.flysaa.com/Journeys/reservation/searchpnr.action?nameSpace=reservation">South African</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Singapore Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://www.singaporeair.com/manageBooking-flow.form?execution=e1s1">Singapore Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='QATAR AIRWAYS')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.qatarairways.com/us/en/homepage.page">QATAR AIRWAYS</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Qantas Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/your-booking/global/en">Qantas Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Malaysia')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://book.malaysiaairlines.com/itd/itd/lang/en/reservations">Malaysia</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Lufthansa')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/us/my_account/my_bookings">Lufthansa</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='KLM - Royal Dutch Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/index.htm#tab=db_mmb">KLM - Royal Dutch Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Japan Air')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.5971.jal.co.jp/eng/SearchReservation.do">Japan Air</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Etihad Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.etihadairways.com/sites/etihad/_layouts/etihad/obe/RetrieveBooking.aspx">Etihad Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Emirates')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://fly.emirates.com/MYB/MMBLogin.aspx">Emirates</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Delta Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.delta.com/">Delta Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Copa Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.copaair.com/sites/US/EN/Pages/homepage.aspx">Copa Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Continental Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.continental.com/web/en-US/apps/reservation/default.aspx">Continental Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Cathay Pacific')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_US/manageyourtrip/managemybooking?loginType=nonmember">Cathay Pacific</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='British Airways')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_us">British Airways</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='American Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://www.aa.com/reservation/findReservationAccess.do">American Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='All Nippon')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://aswbe-i.ana.co.jp/p_per/sky_ip_per_jp/preReConfirmSearchPnr.do?CONNECTION_KIND=LAX&LA...">All Nippon</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Alitalia')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.alitalia.com/US_EN/home/index.aspx">Alitalia</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Alaska Airlines')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://www.alaskaair.com/booking/ssl/saved/ViewPnr.aspx">Alaska Airlines</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Air New Zealand')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://flightbookings.airnewzealand.com/isbook_en_US/review/initNewWebCheckIn.do?workflowAction=...">Air New Zealand</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Air France')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="https://www.airfrance.us/cgi-bin/AF/US/en/local/process/standard/rebooking/SearchPnrRbkAction.do?">Air France</a>';
    }
    else if(etNew.Airline__c =='Air Canada')
    {
        etNew.Airlines_Url__c = '<a href="http://www.aircanada.com/aco/manageMyBookings.do">Air Canada</a>';
    }
  }
}
```

And not able to get 100% code coverage using following test case

```
@isTest
private class ETicketAirlineUrlTestCase {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    Opportunity oppNew =  new Opportunity();
    oppNew.Name = 'Test Opp';
    oppNew.StageName = 'To Be Searched';
    oppNew.CloseDate = System.now().date();
    insert oppNew;

    E_Ticket__c et =  new E_Ticket__c();
    et.Airline__c = 'Virgin Australia';
    et.Opportunity__c = oppNew.Id;
     et.Airline__c = 'Virgin Atlantic';
    insert et;

    E_Ticket__c etNew = [select Id, Airline__c from E_Ticket__c where Id = :et.Id];
    update etNew;
}
}
```

when i run Class-->Force.com-->Run Test it show 100% code coverage

but when i do Force.com-->Deploy To Server it show error 6% covered

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks..

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073987/test-case-for-the-rigger-in-apex

Comment: Hi Anil, please try and write the code yourself before asking others to do all of the work for you. The community is much more likely to help with specific problems (errors you run into, etc.) or best practices for specific tasks. This question is down-voted because, as it says when mousing over the down-vote arrow "This question does not show any research effort...".

Comment: @Matthew i write the test case for trigger but not getting 100% code coverage after mush struggle so that is why i m asking for any help...

Comment: Can you post the code you have, for the test, in the question? That would help.

Comment: @Matthew, i edited the question, sorry for in-complete question..

Comment: Thanks! I removed the down vote.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew , any suggestion on test case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9862/discussion-between-anil-d-and-matthew-keefe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@isTest
private class ETicketAirlineUrlTestCase {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        Opportunity oppNew =  new Opportunity();
        oppNew.Name = 'Test Opp';
        oppNew.StageName = 'To Be Searched';
        oppNew.CloseDate = System.now().date();
        insert oppNew;

        List<E_Ticket__c> tickets = new List<E_Ticket__c>();

        E_Ticket__c et1 =  new E_Ticket__c();
        et1.Airline__c = 'Virgin Australia';
        et1.Opportunity__c = oppNew.Id;
        tickets.add(et1);

        E_Ticket__c et2 =  new E_Ticket__c();
        et2.Airline__c = 'Virgin Atlantic';
        et2.Opportunity__c = oppNew.Id;
        tickets.add(et2);

        // ...
        // add as many tickets needed for all Airlines
        // ...

        insert tickets;
        update tickets;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure custom objects match in both your sandbox and deployment/production server.

Comment: Thanks alot @Matthew, will you please give me some tips on Test Case writing, do we need to cover all if else conditions in test case?

Comment: @AnilD Write test classes to confirm and assert the results.Dont have the test class just to have coverage of 100% . But the primary reason for the test class is to confirm what you are doing in your trigger/class is working fine. if you have if else statements then i would surely have all those covered.

Comment: Prady is right; test classes are meant to confirm your trigger or class is working correctly. Be sure the test runs through all of your code and use [`System.assertEquals`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_example.htm) to make sure everything is works.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get 100% code coverage, you'd need to write a test for each "else if" statement.

You currently only have one test, for one "else if."